# Find Total by weekly

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table `table` with columns `date` and `total`.

How can I aggregate the `sum` of the `total` column by week for the last 20 weeks to `sysdate`?

Comment: Why is this tagged Oracle and MySQL?  Are you wanting to do it for two different RDBMS?

Comment: What is the data type of "date" column? Is it a VARCHAR or a DATE or a TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Actually i need to do it from Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select trunc(date,'D'), sum(total)
from table
where date >= trunc(sysdate - 20*7, 'D')
group by trunc(date,'D')
order by 1
```

Comment: There are different ways of grouping dates in weeks.  The `W`, `WW` and `IW` will produce different dates, although the weekly aggregates won't differ.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(YEAR(`sysdate`), '/', WEEK(`sysdate`)) AS `year_week`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `year_week`
ORDER BY `year_week` DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: You will also need an ORDER BY for getting the "last 20 weeks".

Comment: got this error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: I don't see any kind of Oracle in your question. It is a common SQL.